# GMap.Net draw lines

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmap.net

I'm trying to draw polyline but I can't find any way to do that. I use GMapPolygon but it has extra line between start and end points. Here is my code and sample image;

```
                // Red Dot Markers
                GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(
                    new PointLatLng(lat, longt),
                    GMarkerGoogleType.red_dot);
                gmap.Overlays.Add(reddot_markers);
                reddot_markers.Markers.Add(marker);
                //Red Dot Polygons
                reddot_polygons.Polygons.Clear();
                reddot_points.Add(new PointLatLng(lat, longt));
                GMapPolygon reddot_polygon = new GMapPolygon(reddot_points, "reddot_points");
                reddot_polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
                reddot_polygon.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);
                gmap.Overlays.Add(reddot_polygons);
                reddot_polygons.Polygons.Add(reddot_polygon);
```

[image]

Comment: Would a `GMapRoute` better suit your purposes?

Comment: As per the above comment [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39735458/1599751) might be worth taking a look at. If that helps maybe you could flag this question as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Thank you, it works well. I flagged that question..