# GMap Route creation

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I Need your help: I use GMap in Windows Presentation Foundation and i want to create a route with coordinates. It should be a route **directly** to the other coordinates, because it's a route for an airplane. Is there a function, that allows me to draw something like a line between my coordinates?

P.S. In a database are all the waypoints saved. The user only has to enter the waiponints Name and then the coordinates should be entered to the route.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See following.  Remember not all airline routes go between every city.  Routes only go between major cities and their hubs : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919001/draw-a-polyline-on-the-map-using-gmap-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a demo to draw a line directly to the other coordinates like the below picture:
[image]

1. Create a list to for the marked points

   `List<PointLatLng> pointLatlngs = new List<PointLatLng>();`
2. Add the marked points in the List when the point is marked

   `System.Windows.Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(mapControl);
   PointLatLng point = mapControl.FromLocalToLatLng((int)clickPoint.X, (int)clickPoint.Y);
   pointLatlngs.Add(point);`
3. Draw the line between points

   ```
       for (int i = 0; i < pointLatlngs.Count; i++)
       {
           GMapRoute gmRoute = new GMapRoute(new List<PointLatLng>() {
               pointLatlngs[i] , pointLatlngs.Count-1 == i ? pointLatlngs[i] : pointLatlngs[i + 1]})
           {
               Shape = new Line()
               {
                   StrokeThickness = 3,
                   Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.BlueViolet
               },                  
           };
           mapControl.Markers.Add(gmRoute);             
       }
   ```